# What are the aerodynamic characteristics of the flying saucer?

Tags: aerodynamics, aviation-history

It seems that [Canadian VZ-9 Avrocar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_VZ-9_Avrocar#Operational_history) was aerodynamically unstable. Particularly at high altitudes, and so the project was cancelled. IIRC there was considerable interest in flying saucers in the 1950s and this was one of the most well documented attempts to build one that could actually work.

But is the flying disc a bad design for an aircraft? Especially one that is designed for high speeds high maneuverability. If so please explain the reasons for this.

Comment: I had a professor in school who was a technician on the Avrocar. The whole thing was a goofy dead end, that existed only because someone at the USAF had a bee in his bonnet and was able to get it funded. When you think about it, what was the point of a saucer shape in the first place? Flying saucers were one of the dopier 50s fads.

Comment: @JohnK I think the idea was to make VTOL fairly easy. It wouldn't need a runway and could land in a grassy field and then take right off.

Comment: Yes but why a disc and not some streamlined shape that can be designed to have some kind of static stability in forward flight, like a lifting body. The ACar might have been able to get out of ground effect with more powerful engines, and digital computers controlling the attitude control vanes in the D ring. Anyway, you are still stuck with a massively inefficient flying machine.

Comment: Ah, the '50s... real engineers at work (with a lot of money)...